# Does fire cause friction in the fuel?

Tags: friction, physical-chemistry, combustion

It is possible to create fire by friction. For example - by striking a stone with another stone or by striking a matchstick on a rough surface.

My question is: Can we say that, where there is fire there must be some kind friction in the fuel , at atomic or molecular level?

Comment: friction causes sparks between solids, sparks are not fire.

Comment: @annav Are you saying sparks are not consuming anything like tiny solid to occur ? Are you also saying that no burning is occurring during sparking ? Thanks.

Comment: Sparks produced by striking stones are just heated particles of the stones. After cooling down, they become invisible because of the limitations of the human vision, but one can collect the product of multiple stone hits and it will be just dust-sized stones, chemically identical to the original stone.

Comment: Burning is a chemical reaction between molecules which changes them.  sparks are electrical discharges between accumulated charge by electrons displaced through the forces  on the solid's molecules induced by friction. no change in molecular composition

Comment: [Dust explosions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dust_explosion) can be caused by friction.

Comment: @annav, IDK whether "spark" is a term of art in physics, but in every day use, there are various phenomena that we call "spark" that are not electric arcs. E.g., the shower of burning metal sparks produced by a cutting torch or a grinding wheel.

Comment: @SolomonSlow  If you look at the microscopic details, it will be small electric discharges  too

Answer (score 1):

Friction is a macroscopic thing. You move objects one in regard to another, you get force. The general outcome is little or no chemical change in the objects. Some heat is produced, some parts come apart (or, in some cases, are welded together).

You cannot really define "friction" at molecular level, other than molecules being kicked together.

Fire is (by more or less common definition) a chemical process changing both the air and the fuel. Molecules are rearranged with different atoms getting bound.

Processes are pretty much unrelated.

Fire generally needs high temperature to start and you can get high temperature by friction, but this is not like friction being fire.

On the other hand, you can extend the definition of "fire" to anything producing heat and/or light (some languages do not have this distinction and pretty much need clarifications in this regard).

In this sense, friction can be "fire" even in the case of the two stones striking together.

I am not aware of the reverse - the definition of friction to be extended to something involving substantial change of the objects experiencing friction. But even if it exists, it will be purely a language phenomenon and not a similarity in the underlying process.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we say that, where there is fire there must be some kind friction in the fuel ?

Not necessarily. Fire is the rapid oxidation of a material in an exothermic (heat releasing) reaction. Often this requires an external source of heat to initiate the reaction, and this external heat *can* come from friction - but it can also come from other sources such as an electric spark. It is also possible for substances to spontaneously ignite in air without an external source of heat, in a process called [spontaneous combustion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_combustion).